# Can't pull dynamic info from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 databases that I'm connecting to and trying to run queries against, if I get results from one, I can't match them against the other, however, if I echo the result and type it into the query manually, it works fine.  Any thoughts?

```
//USER SETTINGS STUFF
$users = "SELECT * FROM user_info
        WHERE frequency='daily'";
$result = mysqli_query($sql, $users);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    //EMAIL LOGIN STUFF 
    $username = $row['user_name'] . '<br />';
    echo $username . '<br />'; //echos "dustin"
    $emailquery = "SELECT * FROM users
                WHERE user_name = 'dustin'";
    $eresult = mysqli_query($loginsql, $emailquery);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($eresult)) {
        $emailaddress = $row['user_email']; 
        echo $emailaddress; 
        }//END EMAIL LOGIN WHILE
}//END USER SETTIGS WHILE
```

This query from the above code works perfectly and returns the appropriate email address

```
$emailquery = "SELECT * FROM users
WHERE user_name = 'dustin'";
```

The query below below (which is what i need it to be) doesn't and returns nothing

```
$emailquery = "SELECT * FROM users
WHERE user_name = '$username'";
```

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Remove `<br/>` when assiging to `$username = $row['user_name'];`

Comment: `$username = $row['user_name'] . '<br />'`

Comment: WHY ARE YOU USING CAPITALS??

Comment: You really ought to look into prepared statements with MySqli to avoid sql injection. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: no good answer for the capitals, but I was definitely assigning <br /> to $username instead of echo by accident. Started doing that to test, fixed another small problem and didn't realize I'd done it.  Thanks!

Comment: Try debugging with `echo $emailquery;` - what does it write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you add a line break at the end of your `$username` var. Simply remove the `<br />` and check what's going on.

Replace this line:

```
$username = $row['user_name'] . '<br />';
```

With this:

```
$username = $row['user_name'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$emailquery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '" . $username ."'";
```